# hibernate: Could not execute JDBC batch update

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jdbc

When I want to create a one to one mapping by using hibernate, the error "Could not execute JDBC batch update" keeps raising and I noticed that it was caused by the failure of creating tables in the MySQL according to the error it showed. Would you please help me to find out the problems inside it? Thank you!

Hibernate Configuration File

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
    "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
    "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
<session-factory>
<property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>
<property name="show_sql">true</property>
<property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
<property name="connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost/june13?serverTimezone=UTC</property>
<property name="connection.username">root</property>
<property name="connection.password">root</property>
<property name="connection.driver_class">com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver</property>
<mapping resource="Emp-hbm.xml"/>
</session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

Hibernate one-to-one mapping file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC 
    "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
    "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="com.hibernate.one2one.Emp" table="emp_906">
        <id name="id" column="emp_id"></id>
        <property name="name" column="emp_name" />
        <one-to-one name="phoneno" cascade="all"></one-to-one>
    </class>
    <class name="com.hibernate.one2one.PhoneNumber" table="phone_906">
        <id name="pid"></id>
        <property name="network" />
        <property name="phonenumber" />
        <one-to-one name="emp"></one-to-one>
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

Main File:

```
package com.hibernate.one2one;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.Transaction;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;
import org.hibernate.classic.Session;

public class App 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        Configuration cfg=new Configuration();
        cfg.configure("Hibernate-cfg.xml");
        System.out.println("Configuration Object Created Successfully");
        SessionFactory sf=cfg.buildSessionFactory();
        System.out.println("Session Factory Object is Created");
        Session s=sf.openSession();
        Transaction t=s.beginTransaction();
        Emp e=new Emp();
        e.setId(104);
        e.setName("Lee Meng");
        PhoneNumber ph = new PhoneNumber();
        ph.setPid(201);
        ph.setNetwork("ATT");
        ph.setPhonenumber("9900336611");
        e.setPhoneno(ph);
        ph.setEmp(e);
        s.persist(e);
        t.commit();
        s.close();
        sf.close();
    }
}
```

The error code:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: Could not execute JDBC batch update
    at org.hibernate.exception.SQLStateConverter.convert(SQLStateConverter.java:92)
    at org.hibernate.exception.JDBCExceptionHelper.convert(JDBCExceptionHelper.java:66)
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher.executeBatch(AbstractBatcher.java:275)
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher.prepareStatement(AbstractBatcher.java:114)
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher.prepareStatement(AbstractBatcher.java:109)
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher.prepareBatchStatement(AbstractBatcher.java:244)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2411)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2874)
    at org.hibernate.action.EntityInsertAction.execute(EntityInsertAction.java:79)
    at org.hibernate.engine.ActionQueue.execute(ActionQueue.java:273)
    at org.hibernate.engine.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:265)
    at org.hibernate.engine.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:184)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:321)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:51)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.flush(SessionImpl.java:1216)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.managedFlush(SessionImpl.java:383)
    at org.hibernate.transaction.JDBCTransaction.commit(JDBCTransaction.java:133)
    at com.hibernate.one2one.App.main(App.java:32)
Caused by: java.sql.BatchUpdateException: Table 'june13.emp_906' doesn't exist
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at com.mysql.cj.util.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:192)
    at com.mysql.cj.util.Util.getInstance(Util.java:167)
    at com.mysql.cj.util.Util.getInstance(Util.java:174)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createBatchUpdateException(SQLError.java:224)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeBatchSerially(ClientPreparedStatement.java:853)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeBatchInternal(ClientPreparedStatement.java:435)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.StatementImpl.executeBatch(StatementImpl.java:796)
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.BatchingBatcher.doExecuteBatch(BatchingBatcher.java:70)
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher.executeBatch(AbstractBatcher.java:268)
    ... 15 more
Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Table 'june13.emp_906' doesn't exist
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:120)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:97)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:122)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeInternal(ClientPreparedStatement.java:953)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeUpdateInternal(ClientPreparedStatement.java:1092)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeBatchSerially(ClientPreparedStatement.java:832)
    ... 19 more
```

Comment: "it was caused by the failure of creating tables" - no, this is not true. The error message means that the codes attempts to read from a table, by this table is missing. What should you do? Create a table that is currently missing.

Comment: You use hibernate 5? see https://stackoverf7low.com/questions/33449545/table-not-created-with-hbm2ddl-auto-update-in-hibernate-5 ... (answer with set dialect)

Answer (score 1):

How about adding `<property name="hbm2ddl.auto" value="create"/>` to your hibernate configruation file. This will ensure your tables are created on startup and leave them intact.

> validate: validate the schema, makes no changes to the database.
> update: update the schema. create: creates the schema, destroying
> previous data. create-drop: drop the schema when the SessionFactory is
> closed explicitly, typically when the application is stopped. none:
> does nothing with the schema, makes no changes to the database

A more extensive description of the possible values :
[What are the possible values of the Hibernate hbm2ddl.auto configuration and what do they do](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/438146/what-are-the-possible-values-of-the-hibernate-hbm2ddl-auto-configuration-and-wha)

Answer (score 0):

It is a java error: Please disable/comment out recovery part from MySQL my.cnf file.
As now the MySQL is in a state where users cannot change/edit anything on the MySQL database.